# Positioning a node with "above"

Tags: tikz-pgf

Units do not need to be declared in the specification of the height of a node above a given coordinate using `above`.  The comment in the following example in Chapter 17, Section 5.3 indicates that the number 0.2, without mention of units, is rendered by `TikZ` as 0.2 centimeters (or 2 millimeters).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\node at (1,1) [above=0.2, draw] {above};
% south border of the node is now 2mm above (1,1)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The following code is similar to the code from the manual, except for `[x=2cm,y=2cm]`, which magnifies the graph. The first node is positioned using `above=0.25` and the lower edge of the node is placed 0.5 centimeters above the coordinate; the second node is positioned using `above=0.25cm` and the lower edge of the node is placed 0.25 centimeters above the coordinate.  Where is this distinction discussed in the manual?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
\draw (0,0) grid [xstep=0.5, ystep=0.5] (2,2);
\node at (0.5,1) [above=0.25, draw] {over};
\node at (1.5,1) [above=0.25cm, draw] {over};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The difference is due to `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]`, which tells TikZ to use increments of 2cm in the absence of explicit dimensions. In your example, `above=0.25` means the same as `yshift=0.25*2cm,anchor=south`. Note this only happens if you load the `positioning` library. The following example may help clarify.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
\draw (0,0) grid [xstep=1, ystep=1] (4,4);
\node at (0.5,1) [blue,above=1, circle, draw] {over};
\node at (1.5,1) [red,yshift=1cm,anchor=south, circle, draw] {over};
\node at (2.5,1) [above=1cm, draw] {over};
\node at (3.5,1) [above=10mm, draw] {over};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=2cm]
\draw (0,0) grid [xstep=1, ystep=1] (4,4);
\node at (0.5,1) [blue,above=1, circle, draw] {over};
\node at (1.5,1) [red,yshift=1cm,anchor=south, circle, draw] {over};
\node at (2.5,1) [above=1cm, draw] {over};
\node at (3.5,1) [above=10mm, draw] {over};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your first picture, I don't think you need to specify `[x=1cm,y=1cm]`.  Did you just state that for emphasis?

Comment: I have one question that is not relevant to my post. How would I have "over" typeset in a color that is different than the circle or rectangle enclosing it?

Comment: You clarified the situation for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just for emphasis.

Comment: The options `[blue, draw=red]` will make the text blue, but will draw the object in red.

Comment: Can you give me a reference in the manual for this?  I have wasted an hour looking for this!

Comment: Based on your post, it seems you're already using the TikZ manual. In addition to that and this site, the only thing I might suggest is checking examples posted at [texample.net](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/)

Comment: @ Yeah, the `TikZ` manual should have an illustrative example of this.  I did not find it, though.  I doubt the manual has it.  I will have to remember that if two colors are specified in the options, the one immediately following `draw=` draws the shape in that color.

Comment: There are `fill`, `draw`, and `text` (if not more), so it's probably best to be explicit.